# Maven dependency not getting resolved in Intellij

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

I have Maven setup and updated settings.xml with proxy settings. While working on project it is unable to load any dependency in IntelliJ.

I verified all the config with one of my friend and its working in his machine correctly. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure that you are pointing to correct `settings.xml` in the configuration of `intellij`
Go to-->File-->Settings-->Build,Execution,Deployment-->Mavan

and validate user settings file and local repository file, if its having different details update the path or replace the file.

[image: intellij-->File-->Settings-->Build-->Mavan]